# How to detect if this is an ISP/Server cache?

Tags: ubuntu, cache

Before we start: I'm a noob.

I'm trying to access YQL to get some information. Grabbing it using PHP's file_get_contents is simple enough, but it seems like either the client's ISP or the server is caching the response. To illustrate the problem, try loading:

--

Refresh that page a couple of times - notice that the 'created' string doesn't change - it should be a couple of seconds off each time you refresh, like this test sample:

--

Now my question is, is this some sort of trick by the sysadmin to cache things, or something that the ISP do? Can I get around it? I must access the YQL via URL because I need to be able to parse it.

(The sysadmin is difficult to reach)

Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT**

I've found out how to get around the cache. You can either randomize string and use the trick mentioned by @Coops below, or use the code here. Most of the times, you can skip the cache by sending Pragma: no-cache header, create a context and use it:

```
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
    'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Pragma: no-cache"
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://example.com');
```

I still can't figure out whether the cache is configured by sysadmin or the ISP though.

Comment: a general tip, you can add "?blah" on the end of the URL to make it a dynamic request and avoid some browser caches. Also I've used a javascript function in the past to append a random number on the end of the request to some google APIs, as they cache a lot.

Comment: @Coops - that's a neat trick! Thanks! I've figured out how to do it the other way though, I'll edit the question in case someone happens to have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can check some specific headers from responses: `Age`, `Expires`, `ETag`, `Via`. Values of this headers can help you to determine whatever you need.
For details and header descriptions see section `Responses` in [List of HTTP headers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields).

For example, value of `Via` header can tell you that response was received from Proxy which can have requested by you data in his own cache.

Comment: agree - have a good look at the headers or maybe post them up here. `wget --spider -S http://www.foo.com/`